# Есть ли отличия?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Чем синтаксически отличаются два случая?

> (1) - Молодец! Саша, ты так хорошо выступил!
>   (2) - Саша, ты так хорошо выступил! Молодец!

В первом случае **Молодец!** - неполное предложение, а во втором - постпозитивный номинатив с функцией оценки?

Answer (score 3):

Если, к примеру, фигурист Саша только что откатал программу, то тренер ему говорит: "Молодец! Саша, ты так хорошо выступил!"

В первой фразе *Молодец*! —  **номинативное предложение со значением оценки** (впечатление от выступления).

Во второй фразе — это  **постпозитивный номинатив** с функцией оценки.

Comment: Разве оценочные предложения типа "Молодец!", относящиеся к лицу, без частиц, в конечном счете не признают неполным?

Comment: Мне кажется, что оценка может относиться к лицу, предмету, явлению. У Кустовой есть пример из "Вишневого сада", где Трофимов дразнит Варю, а она говорит сердить: Облезлый барин! Это восприятие предмета и оценка его в момент речи.  Сравнить: Сам ты облезлый барин! (двусоставное предложение)

Answer (score 1):

Они различаются степенью переполненности (говорящего) эмоциями. В первом случае он не удержался от похвальной оценки адресата и начал с неё. Во втором - сначала изложил причины такой оценки. Других различий не видно.

Comment: Alex_ander, автор просит указать не смысловые, а синтаксические различия, а для этого надо определить вид предложения в каждом случае.

Comment: Александр, простите, что не по теме. Не поможете с вопросом: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/202691/the-correct-pronunciation-of-where-is? А то никто не отвечает. Буду благодарен, если ответите, этим и поднимете его, а там, может, ещё кто подтянется.

Comment: Посмотрим, что люди скажут :)

Comment: Ага) Спасибо большое! =)